# Skip Rest of the string if found character

Tags: java, string, trim

Hi i have following string as output from server.

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDppbmNvbWluZz9jbGllbnROYW1lPWplbm55IHNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVA2YmI2NDI1ZmE3MTU3MzdmYjFmYTllMjI1MDk4NjdlMSZhcHBQYXJhbXM9JmNsaWVudE5hbWU9amVubnkiLCJpc3MiOiJBQzI4YmNjYzc0NzQ4ZDAzNzRmNzg5ZjgyN2U0OGMzODNjIiwiZXhwIjoxMzYxNDM0ODY1fQ.q17gvt8ItDmximK2rpS5bHwtsfbk3l-suSx2jXju3Wk
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

I want to skip html part of the string ie i only want

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDppbmNvbWluZz9jbGllbnROYW1lPWplbm55IHNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVA2YmI2NDI1ZmE3MTU3MzdmYjFmYTllMjI1MDk4NjdlMSZhcHBQYXJhbXM9JmNsaWVudE5hbWU9amVubnkiLCJpc3MiOiJBQzI4YmNjYzc0NzQ4ZDAzNzRmNzg5ZjgyN2U0OGMzODNjIiwiZXhwIjoxMzYxNDM0ODY1fQ.q17gvt8ItDmximK2rpS5bHwtsfbk3l-suSx2jXju3Wk
```

And i want to remove following from the string

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

What method i should use to detect `<!--` and skip rest of the string?

Comment: Those two strings look exactly identical?

Comment: something is wrong with your question. Both strings are the same and you forgot to write what do you want to remove. I cannot see any HTML part in posted string

Comment: Your HTML tags aren't showing up. Surround the two strings with backticks ` to keep them from being parsed as HTML.

Comment: Fixed it, they were html comments so got skipped :P

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: If the `String` actually includes the newline characters, it would be easiest to split on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the analytics comment you're trying to remove is always at the end of your String, you could do something like:

```
String s = "...";
int pos = s.indexOf("<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->");
if (pos >= 0) { s = s.substring(0, pos); }
// continue working with s
```

If it's somewhere in the middle of your String, you may need additional indexOf() calls to find the start and end of what you want to remove. Note that this method returns -1 when the substring isn't found.

```
s.substring(a, b);
```

will return the subsequence of characters in s that starts at position a and ends at position b - 1 (if a==b then the resulting string is empty).

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "inputString";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char ch;
boolean check=false;
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    ch = s.charAt(i);
    if(ch == '<')
    {
        check = false;
    }
    if(ch == '>')
    {
        check = true;
        ch = s.charAt(i);
    }
    if(check)
        sb.append(ch);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<.*", "");
```